# Декомпозиция в python. Как передать параметры в функцию?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу передать в функцию словарь с аргументами.

Например, в `javascript` можно сделать так:

```
const dict = {
   a: 1,
   b: 2,
};

function test(incomingDict) {
  const {a, b} = incomingDict;
}

test(dict)
```

А как в `python` такое повторить?

Пришло в голову так:

```
dict = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
}

def test(incoming_dict):
    a = incoming_dict["a"]
    b = incoming_dict["b"]

test(dict)
```

Есть идеи? Как "красиво" передавать множество параметров... Больше пяти, скажем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно передать через "двойную звездочку", тогда словарь распакуется в параметры с соответствующими ключам именами:

```
d = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
}

def test(a, b):
    print(a, b)  # Выведет 1, 2

test(**d)
```

Comment: Ок, а в методе мне его распаковать как? Понимаю, что можно сделать **b, но тогда b станет словарем.

Comment: Ну, можно сделать `a, b = d.values()`, но будет брать значения из словаря последовательно, и не факт, что имена переменных будут соответствовать ключам. Проще именно при передаче словаря распаковать, как в ответе.

Comment: Для этого нужно, чтобы метод/функция заранее имели количество входных параметров, идентичное словарю, верно? Или я не прав? И еще вопрос, а что если параметры функции/метода: c, d. Тогда а из словаря = с, верно?

Comment: Можно так сделать, тогда "лишние" параметры из словаря окажутся в словаре kwargs: `def test(a, b, **kwargs):`. Вообще, возможно тут уже имеет смысл вместо передачи большого количества параметров объекты передавать.

Comment: Объекты не подойдут. Я так зависимости передаю. Дальше, в инициализаторе назначаю как self.param. Что позволит делать инъекцию зависимостей.

Comment: Ок, а касательно второго вопроса: а что если параметры функции/метода: c, d. Тогда а из словаря = с, верно? Каков тут порядок?

Comment: Если в словаре c и d, то и параметры должны быть c и d.

Comment: То есть передача идет как с=значение из словаря. Я Вас понял, спасибо Вам.